# Searching for a filename without a certain string

Tags: command-line, find

So when you want to search for a file with a filename containing the string xyz from a directory to all depths, you write

```
sudo find path -name '*xyz*'
```

How do I find all files *without* the string xyz?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add a `!` (not) before the expression:

```
sudo find path ! -name '*xyz*'
```

Comment: Negation is also particularly useful when searching for permissions that are not set correctly -e.g. find <path> -type f ! -perm -444 or find <path> -type d ! -perm -111. For more on find see http://www.pixelbeat.org/cmdline.html.

Comment: I think I'd tried this and it didn't work. Maybe I'd put the '!' in a different place? Anyway, this worked perfectly. And thanks for the tip, @Mik

Comment: You probably need to quote the `!`, i.e. use `\!`.

Comment: I tried it as is and it wasn't necessary to use \!.

Answer (score 3):

To search for files not containing `'*xyz*`' do:

```
sudo find path -type f -not -name '*xyz*'
```

To search for paths (files and directories) not containing `'*xyz*'` do:

```
sudo find path -not -path '*xyz*'
```

To search case-insensitively prepend name or path with `i`, i.e. `-iname` or `-ipath`.