# How to delete all first-level subfolders that do not have a specified string in their names

Tags: command-line, directory, delete, filename

I know that there are quite a lot of answered questions about how to delete all **files** *with* or *without* a certain string in their names, as well as ones about how to delete all **subfolders** *with* a certain string in their names.

Yet, there are no questions regarding how to delete all **subfolders** *without* a certain string in there names.

So, as I have recently ran into such a problem, is there a quick command that will help with this situation? A bash script would be good enough, too.

**EDIT**:

By **subfolders**, I meant only the first-level subfolders, because I don't want to remove second-level or third-level subfolders, which might have names without the string, of first-level subfolders with the string.

Comment: Try `find . -type d -not -name "*substring*"`. If that turns up the right subfolders, add the `-delete` flag. Does that work?

Comment: Some nspiration could come from here: http://askubuntu.com/q/163960/57576 :)

Comment: @Jos Please note that `-delete` only works for empty directories. If you need to delete the directory and its content, you must use `-exec rm -rf {} \;` instead.

Comment: You are correct @ByteCommander. Let's turn this into an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let us say you want to start `find` in the current directory, and restrict it to the first level of subdirectories:

`find . -maxdepth 1`

The `find` command has a useful flag `-not` (or `!`) which negates the following test. So in order to find a name which does *not* contain a substring, add

`-not -name "*substring*"`

IMPORTANT: you will want to exclude the current directory itself as well. Otherwise, the whole current directory would be deleted.

`-not -name "."`

Then you want to test for directories only:

`-type d`

And, if everything looks good, you want to delete these directories:

`-exec rm -rf {} \;`

which says "for all found directories, execute this command". The `{}` is a *placeholder* for the name of the directory (including the full path, so it works on the correct one). `\;` indicates the end of the command to be executed.

Summarizing:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -not -name "*substring*" -not -name "." -type d -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

should work. But first, try it out without the `-exec` part.

Comment: @PyGeek03 I did.

Comment: Well, 1 more thing with this command though: the output without `-exec rm -rf {} \;` part also include . , so when I run the whole command, the content of the whole directory got deleted! (I've made a backup, as this is a test anyway). Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: Good point. Will add that as well.

Comment: Use a plus `+` in place of the escaped semicolon.  The `find` will run the `rm` command with multiple arguments, rather like using `xargs` would.

Answer (score 4):

The bash shell's *extended glob* operators can do pattern negation e.g. given

```
$ tree .
.
├── subdir
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
├── subdirbar
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
├── subdirbaz
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
└── subdirfoo
    ├── other file
    └── somefile

4 directories, 8 files
```

then if extended globbing is enabled (`shopt -s extglob`)

```
$ rm -rf !(*foo*)
```

removes (recursively) all top-level directories not containing string `foo`, leaving

```
$ tree
.
└── subdirfoo
    ├── other file
    └── somefile

1 directory, 2 files
```

**However**, this would also delete any *files* with names not containing `foo` in the top level. AFAIK bash extended globs can't distinguish files from directories - but zsh provides *glob qualifiers*, which allow that e.g. given

```
 % tree
.
├── foofile
├── other file
├── somefile
├── subdir
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
├── subdirbar
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
├── subdirbaz
│   ├── other file
│   └── somefile
└── subdirfoo
    ├── other file
    └── somefile

4 directories, 11 files
```

then in `zsh`

```
 % setopt EXTENDED_GLOB

 % ls -d (^(*foo*))   
other file  somefile  subdir  subdirbar  subdirbaz
```

whereas adding the `(/)` directory qualifier

```
 % ls -d (^(*foo*))(/)
subdir  subdirbar  subdirbaz
```

so

```
 % rm -rf (^(*foo*))(/)
```

removes only *directories* whose names do not include string `foo`, leaving plain files intact.

```
 % tree
.
├── foofile
├── other file
├── somefile
└── subdirfoo
    ├── other file
    └── somefile

1 directory, 5 files
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me a good reason to give zsh a try :))) Turns out it is much more advanced than bash, which is a good thing :D