# Remove all directories from within a parent directory except one and its descendents

Tags: filesystem, directory, directory-structure

[image: directory structure]

I want to remove directory B and D. But i want to keep C and all its descendent files and directories. What's the command to remove all children directories of a parent directory except one directory and its children.

Help appreciated.

Comment: are the directories that you wish to remove empty?

Comment: Related: [How to delete all first-level subfolders that do not have a specified string in their names](http://askubuntu.com/questions/799274/how-to-delete-all-first-level-subfolders-that-do-not-have-a-specified-string-in)

Comment: What about files directly located in the parent directory (`A` in your example)? Delete them as well or keep them?

Comment: What Byte Commander is asking is , are there any files in A ? or only directories ? Do you want regular files in A removed or only directories ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you want is this command:

```
find ~/TESTDIR -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not \( -name "keepMe" \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

#### Demo:

```
# List what's inside directory we want to remove
$ ls
file1  file2  keepMe/  removeA/  removeB/
＃　Testing what find gives without removing
$ find ~/TESTDIR -mindepth 1 -type d -not \( -name "keepMe" \)               
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/removeA
/home/xieerqi/TESTDIR/removeB
# Actual removal and testls
$ find ~/TESTDIR -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -not \( -name "keepMe" \) -exec rm -rf {} \;
$ ls
file1  file2  keepMe/
```

#### Explanation:

- `find DIRECTORY` call find command to operate upon DIRECTORY
- `-mindepth 1` : work only with contents of the directory , avoid directory itself which is level 0
- `-maxdepth 1` : prevents descending into subdirectories ( `rm -rf` is recursive anyway, so we don't need to descend into subdirectories to remove them )
- `-type d` : search only for directories
- `-not \( -name "keepMe" \)` ignore item with the name you want to keep
- `-exec rm -rf {} \;` perform removal on each found item

Comment: Great explanation. Too many keystrokes for me though...

Comment: `find` is a good friend here, but Bash's `for` and `test` are better friends... >:-D

Answer (score 8):

Using the bash shell's *extended glob* features (which are enabled by default in current Ubuntu installations), given

```
$ tree A
A
├── B
├── C
│   ├── ac1
│   └── ac2
└── D

5 directories, 0 files
```

you can address everything excluding `C` and its contents using the glob expression `A/!(C)` i.e.

```
$ echo A/!(C)
A/B A/D
```

So to *remove* everything except directory `C` and its contents you can simply use

```
rm -rf A/!(C)
```

leaving

```
$ tree A
A
└── C
    ├── ac1
    └── ac2

3 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: It is amazing to know about this feature. It works great after I ssh and manually run but I get ` "-bash: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('"` when I run it remotely via `ssh $VM_ADDRESS "rm -rf $APP_FOLDER/!(node_modules)"`. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @renatoargh the `extglob` shell option is only enabled for interactive shells - not sure if you can force `ssh` to do that

Answer (score 5):

One  easy way would be to use trash-cli

you can install it with `sudo apt-get install trash-cli`

once installed you can navigate to the parent directory A with `cd /A` and then issue the command
`trash B D` where B and D are the directories you want to remove (they will end up in the trash bin for the drive they are on so if you make a mistake you can recover the files)

Tested under Ubuntu 16.04 and 14.04

Comment: Could this be simplified with something like `trash ! C` ?

Comment: @Serg Nope `trash: cannot trash non existent `!'`

Comment: @Serg and C gets trashed...

Comment: Found it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/216995/3701431  It requires enabling `extglob` though .

Comment: @Serg Depending on the job at hand that might be quite useful! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Simply use Bash's `for` loop and `test` to filter the desired directories and the `rm -rf` command to recursively delete directories, like this:

```
for x in /path/to/parent/*; do test "$x" != "dir_survive" && rm -rf "$x"; done
```

This iterates over all elements (files and directories) inside `/path/to/parent/` and deletes the element recursively if its name is not equal to `dir_survive`. If the parent directory is the current directory, you may only write `*` as path.

If you are unsure and want to test which elements would get deleted first without taking any action, simply replace the `rm -rf` in the command above with `echo` and it will only output the delete candidates.

Here's an example run:

```
$ tree
.
├── dir1
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2
│   └── subdir2
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
├── dir2
│   ├── subdir1
│   │   ├── file1
│   │   └── file2
│   └── subdir2
│       ├── file1
│       └── file2
└── dir_survive
    ├── subdir1
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    └── subdir2
        ├── file1
        └── file2

9 directories, 12 files

$ for x in *; do test "$x" != "dir_survive" && rm -rf "$x"; done

$ tree
.
└── dir_survive
    ├── subdir1
    │   ├── file1
    │   └── file2
    └── subdir2
        ├── file1
        └── file2

3 directories, 4 files
```